# Prove that, for all $x,y$ in the reals, $|\log (4+x^2)-\log(4+y^2)| \leq |0.5(x-y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove that, for all $x,y$ in the reals, $\log (4+x^2)-\log(4+y^2) \leq 0.5(x-y)$

I know that the mean value theorem is supposed to be used to solve this but I’m unsure of how to apply it.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669410/prove-that-x-ln4x2-has-only-one-real-solution/3669446?r=SearchResults#3669446) could be related

Comment: Note that there should be absolute value signs somewhere. In this case the statement is not true, take for example $x = -1$ and $y=1$. I would replace $0.5(x-y)$ with $\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$. Then you might aswell put absolute value signs on the left side of the inequality.

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally missed off the absolute value signs

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by the formula
$$
f(x) \colon= \log \left( 4 + x^2 \right) \ \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Let $x$ and $y$ be any real numbers.

First, suppose that $x < y$. Then the function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[x, y]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(x, y)$. So there exists a real number $t \in (x, y)$ such that 
$$
f(y) - f(x) = f^\prime(t) (y-x),
$$
that is,
$$
\log \left( 4 + y^2 \right) - \log \left( 4 + x^2 \right) = \frac{ 2t }{ 4 + t^2 } (y-x). \tag{1}
$$

Now consider the function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(t) \colon= \frac{ 2t}{ 4 + t^2} \ \mbox{ for all } t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Then
$$
g^\prime (t) = \frac{ 2 }{ 4 + t^2} - \frac{ 4t^2 }{ \left( 4 + t^2 \right)^2 } = \frac{ 8 - 2t^2 }{ \left( 4 + t^2 \right)^2 } = \frac{ 2 \left( 4- t^2 \right) }{ \left( 4 + t^2 \right)^2 } = - \frac{ 2( t-2) (t + 2) }{ \left( 4 + t^2 \right)^2 } .
$$
Thus $g^\prime$ is positive for $t \in (-2, 2)$, zero for $t = \pm 2$, and negative for $t \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (2, +\infty)$. So $g$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty, -2]$, strictly increasing on $[-2, 2]$, and again strictly decreasing on $[2, +\infty)$, and $g$ has a relative minimum value of $-1/2$ at $t = -2$ and a relative maximum value of $1/2$ at $t = 2$. Furthermore we note that 
$$
\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} g(t) = \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \frac{ \frac{2}{t} }{ \frac{4}{t^2} + 1 } = 0.
$$
Thus $g$ decreases from $0$ to $-1/2$ on $(-infty, -2]$, then increases from $-1/2$ to $1/2$ on $[-2, 2]$, and decreases again from $1/2$ to $0$ on $[2, +\infty)$. Therefore we can conclude that, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \leq g(t) \leq \frac{1}{2},
$$
which is the same as 
$$
\left\lvert \frac{ 2t }{ 4 + t^2 } \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{2}. \tag{2}
$$

Now using (2) in (1) above we find that, for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x < y$, we have 
$$
f(y) - f(x) \leq \frac{1}{2} (y-x) = \frac{1}{2} \lvert y - x \rvert. \tag{3}
$$

Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ in (3) above, we can conclude that, for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $y < x$, we have 
$$
f(x) - f(y) \leq \frac{1}{2} (x-y) = \frac{1}{2} \lvert x- y \rvert. \tag{4}
$$

From (3) and (4) together we can conclude that, for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x \neq y$, we obtain 
$$
\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2} \lvert x-y \rvert. \tag{5}
$$
And (5) of course also holds trivially when $x = y$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is equivalent to :

$$(x+y)\frac{\log(x^2+4)-\log(y^2+4)}{x^2-y^2}\leq 0.5$$

This is just the [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean)

We have :

$a=x^2+4$ and $b=y^2+4$ where $a> b$ :

$$\frac{a-b}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$

On the other hand your inequality says :

$$\frac{a-b}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}\geq 2(\sqrt{a-4}+\sqrt{b-4})$$

Wich is true since :

$$\sqrt{ab}\geq 2(\sqrt{a-4}+\sqrt{b-4})$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{without \ loss \ of \ generality \ assume \ y>x}$
then  apply  LMVT on the  function $\ln(4+{x^2})$ on the interval  $(x, y)$

which yeilds $$\frac{\ln(4+{x^2})-\ln(4+{y^2})}{x-y}= \frac{2c}{4+{c^2}} \le \dfrac{1}{2} $$